# Formatter in 'Bar with negative stack': this.point.stackTotal has the wrong value (bug?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, charts, highcharts

I am using HighChart specifically the chart called `Bar with negative stack`. The example is here http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-negative-stack .

I have 2 series, the one on the left and the one on the right.

I want to show a tooltip that shows, in case the mouseover is fired the series on the left, the actual value of the left series and then the total (the value of the left series plus the value of the right series).

So I am using `this.y` as value of just one series, and `this.point.stackTotal` as the total.
But the total is wrong: it is always the same of `this.y`.
In other charts (vertical with stacked column) this works.

Is it a bug?

Comment: Can you show the code /Jsfiddle?

Comment: I specified a link to the documentation. There you can find the js fiddle.
I actually solved calculating that total value by myself. But it is not the most elegant solution in this way.

Comment: Let me aplain stacking in Highcharts: each side(neg/pos) has own stack. When getting stackTotal it means sum of all points, for the same `x` and the same `stack` id for one side. In your case, you have only one point for each negative/positive stack, so `sum`==`y`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick function to calculate the total yourself:

```
       tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                var s = 'Y:' + this.y + '<br/>';
                var pIdx = this.point.index;
                var total = 0;
                $.each(this.series.chart.series, function(i,j){
                    total +=  j.points[pIdx].y;  
                });
                s += 'Total:' + total;
                return s;
            }
        },
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7qf749bw/).

Comment: Thanks, btw as I specified in the comment I already implemented it

Comment: @GiovanniBitliner, yes I saw.  But it's important for the health of this site that questions get answered and closed.  If your implementation is different/better, please answer your own question and accept that answer.